# AWS DocumentDB connecting with python and TLS pem bundle questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

We use AWS fargate with a python project. AWS default setup is using a PEM file when connecting. I know I can turn of TLS.

My coworker says he doesn't want to store credentials in the same repo as code. What is the recommended storage location of that file?
Why do I need it when the servers inside a VPC?
Do I need a different PEM file if I create a cluster on AWS govcloud or does the bundle include all I need?
Do I need it if I'm using an AWS linux 2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answers:

1. You can store the PEM file anywhere(same repository, or any other repository where the code can pull from), but it should be accessible to the code when making an encrypted connection and perform server validation.
2. The communication between the servers in VPC is private, but using a server certificate provides an extra layer of security by validating that the connection is being made to an Amazon DocumentDB cluster.
3. An Amazon DocumentDB cluster in GovCloud region should have a similar separate bundle for TLS connection.
4. Even if you are using Amazon Linux 2 instance, the PEM certificate file would need to be stored on the instance to allow the code to refer it and validate when opening a connection.

It is always a best practice from security point of view to use TLS and authenticate the server with the certificate.